# How to get text of NumericUpDown before valuechanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I want to make it work this way: when I write to NumericUpDown 1k the value should be 1000, when I write 4M the value should be 4000000. How can I make it?
I tried this:

```
private void NumericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyValue == (char)Keys.K)
    {
        NumericUpDown1.Value = NumericUpDown1.Value * 1000;
    }
}
```

But it works with the original value that I wrote.

I want to make it work as a macroses. For example, If I want to get NUD1.Value 1000, I write 1 and then, when I press K the NUD1.Value becomes 1000.

Comment: You can't use a `NumericUpDown` control to accept natural-language input. I don't believe you can use `NumericUpDown` to convert `"4K"` of input into a `.Value = 4000`. You'll have to use a separate `TextBox` for that, I imagine.

Comment: _"But it works with old value, now which i was written"_ What does that mean? What is `FrequencyCW`? Are you getting the value from another NUP control? Side note: Don't name your control `NumericUpDown` because that's the type name and things will get confusing very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume we have a NumericUpDown named `numericUpDown1`. Whenever the user presses <kbd>k</kbd>, we want to multiply the current value of the NUP by 1,000, and if the user presses <kbd>m</kbd>, the current value should be multiplied by 1,000,000. We also don't want the original value to trigger the `ValueChanged` event. So, we need to have a `bool` variable to indicate that the value is being updated.

Here's a complete example:

```
private bool updatingValue;

private void numericUpDown1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData != Keys.K && e.KeyData != Keys.M) return;

    int multiplier = (e.KeyData == Keys.K ? 1000 : 1000000);

    decimal newValue = 0;
    bool overflow = false;
    try
    {
        updatingValue = true;
        newValue = numericUpDown1.Value * multiplier;
    }
    catch (OverflowException)
    {
        overflow = true;
    }
    updatingValue = false;

    if (overflow || newValue > numericUpDown1.Maximum)
    {
        // The new value is greater than the NUP maximum or decimal.MaxValue.
        // So, we need to abort.
        // TODO: you might want to warn the user (or just rely on the beep sound).
        return;
    }

    numericUpDown1.Value = newValue;
    numericUpDown1.Select(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString().Length, 0);
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

And the `ValueChanged` event handler should be something like this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (updatingValue) return;

    // Simulating some work being done with the value.
    Console.WriteLine(numericUpDown1.Value);
}
```

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure I understand. Right now, if you type 1 and then press k, the value becomes 1000. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: I want to make it work as a macroses. For example If I want to get NUD1.Value 1000, I should only write 1K, (should work when I press K NUD1.Value instantaneously becomes equal 1000). Can i make it using NumericUpDown?

Comment: @Daniel Repeating the same comment is hardly an answer to my question. What _exactly_ does not work as expected with the code above?

Comment: Thank you very match, for help!!! I tried this code and this work almost properly. Can I somehow make it without valuechanged event. For example when I write 1 and press K the value should change to 1000 instantaneously. But now I have value change to 1 and then value change to 1000. The problem is that I have some logics with valuechanged event (the value is sent to device and it should send 1000 not 1 and then 1000).

Comment: @Daniel Do you see the `ValueChanged` event being used anywhere in the code above? No. If you use the code above exactly as is, you should get 1000 as soon as you press k after typing 1. Perhaps you're doing something else in the `ValueChanged` event in your actual code and it's interrupting the `KeyDown` code making it not work as expected? If so, you should probably get rid of that part.

Comment: @Daniel Addressing your comment edit: I get what you mean now. In that case, you can have a `bool` variable to indicate that the value is being updated and check it inside the `ValueChanged` event. Let me update the answer to include that.

Comment: @Daniel See the full example above.